# Apple TV: Automatically download new podcasts

Tags: itunes, appletv

Is there a way to get Apple TV to periodically check for new podcasts and download them, like iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to have your Apple TV configured to sync with iTunes and change those preferences on the computer to which your Apple TV is paired to.

The system is most effective when you tell iTunes to be the master and Apple TV to be slave.